# Filling pandas DataFrame with values from another DataFrame of different shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df2 containing four columns: A, B, C, D. I want to fill this dataframe with the values from another data frame temp= (1, 2, 6.5, 8, 3, 4, 6.6, 7.8, 5, 6, 5, 4).

[image: problem_task]

What I want to obtain is given in

[image: df2 dataframe]

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If  length of values modulo 4 is equal `0` seelct first row to `Series` by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), convert to numpy array and reshape by `-1` for by default counts number of `rows` and `4` for number of columns:

```
print (len(df.iloc[0]) % 4)
0

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[0].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
print (df2)
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  2.0  6.5  8.0
1  3.0  4.0  6.6  7.8
2  5.0  6.0  5.0  4.0
```